# Start app and load data with viewpager AsyncTask

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

I'm using AsyncTask with Viewpager and so far everything is working properly. When I run my application everything works fine and displays the data by sliding from one column to another. But when you start the app the data in that first column does not appear. I have tried in the onCreate insert the following code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    url = "1";
    layout = R.id.lista;
    empty = R.id.empty;
    DownloadJSON newTask = new DownloadJSON(url,layout,empty);
    newTask.execute();
    ...
```

It does not work. The app is closed. How do I can load this data when the app starts?

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ViewPager vp;
private vpAdapter myAdapter;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
ListView listview;
String url;
int layout;
int empty;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ctx = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    myAdapter = new vpAdapter();
    vp.setAdapter(myAdapter);


vp.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {
                                 //CASE 0 = FIRST PAGE
            switch (i) {
            case 0:
                url = "1";
                layout = R.id.lista;
                empty = R.id.empty;
                DownloadJSON newTask = new DownloadJSON(url,layout,empty);
                newTask.execute();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            case 1:
                url = "2";
                layout = R.id.lista2;
                empty = R.id.empty2;
                DownloadJSON newTask2 = new DownloadJSON(url,layout,empty);
                newTask2.execute();
                break;
            case 2:
                url = "3";
                layout = R.id.lista3;
                empty = R.id.empty3;
                DownloadJSON newTask3 = new DownloadJSON(url,layout,empty);
                newTask3.execute();
                break;
            case 3:
                url = "4";
                layout = R.id.lista4;
                empty = R.id.empty4;
                DownloadJSON newTask4 = new DownloadJSON(url,layout,empty);
                newTask4.execute();
                break;
            case 4:
                url = "5";
                layout = R.id.lista5;
                empty = R.id.empty5;
                DownloadJSON newTask5 = new DownloadJSON(url,layout,empty);
                newTask5.execute();
                break;
            case 5:
                url = "6";
                layout = R.id.lista6;
                empty = R.id.empty6;
                DownloadJSON newTask6 = new DownloadJSON(url,layout,empty);
                newTask6.execute();
                break;
            }   
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String givemeurl;
    int givemelayout;
    int givemeempty;

    public DownloadJSON(String url, int layout, int empty) {
        this.givemeurl = url;
        this.givemelayout = layout;
        this.givemeempty = empty;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(layout);
        if(listview.getCount()==0){
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Cargando...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }else{
            cancel(true);
            Log.e("CANCELADO","CANCELADO");
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create an array
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("URL");

        if(jsonobject != null){         
            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("productos");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    map.put("imagen", jsonobject.getString("imagen"));
                    map.put("nombre", jsonobject.getString("nombre"));
                    map.put("total", jsonobject.getString("total"));
                    map.put("empresa", jsonobject.getString("empresa"));
                    map.put("unidades", jsonobject.getString("unidades"));
                    map.put("precionuevo", jsonobject.getString("precionuevo")+" €");
                    map.put("precioantiguo", jsonobject.getString("precioantiguo")+" €");
                    map.put("descripcion", jsonobject.getString("descripcion"));
                    map.put("direccion", jsonobject.getString("direccion"));
                    map.put("telefono", jsonobject.getString("telefono"));
                    map.put("latitud", jsonobject.getString("latitud"));
                    map.put("longitud", jsonobject.getString("longitud"));
                    map.put("codeqr", jsonobject.getString("codeqr"));
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                //e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());         
            }
        }else{
            //Log.e("Response","No data");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(givemelayout);
        listview.setEmptyView(findViewById(givemeempty));
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        //Log.e("",""+listview.getCount());
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the rest of your DownloadJSON class? The important part about updating the ViewPager is the onPostExecute() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a better performance, You should download all of the data, before showing the view pager. Currently you're downloading the same data again and again, whenever the user swipes the view pager. And not seeing any data on the first page initially is an expected result, because you download data only in onPageChangeListener. My suggestion is:

1. Create a dummy activity and make it launcher. It will be for downloading data. You can also do some configurations initially.
2. In `onCreate` method of that activity, download all of the necessary data your app needs using an `AsyncTask`.
3. In `onPostExecute` method of that `AsyncTask` start your main intent.
4. And finish the dummy activity to remove it from the stack so that when the user clicks back, your dummy activity won't be seen.

You can either pass the data you got to your main intent with:

- Setting them as extras to your intent, using putExtra
- Or you can store them in Application class, this is the only class that won't be destroyed by Android OS, so it's safe to store data there.